# Various errors running unit tests with TYPO3 testing framework

Tags: phpunit, typo3, typo3-8.x

I am trying to run the unit tests for some of my extensions, using a local, composer-based TYPO3 8.7 installation. Here's my composer file:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git" },
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/cobwebch/external_import.git"},
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/fsuter/externalimport_test.git"},
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/cobwebch/svconnector.git"},
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/cobwebch/svconnector_csv.git"},
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/cobwebch/svconnector_feed.git"},
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/cobwebch/svconnector_json.git"},
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/cobwebch/svconnector_sql.git"}
  ],
  "name": "my-vendor/my-typo3-cms-distribution",
  "require": {
    "typo3/cms": "TYPO3_8-7-dev",
    "cobweb/external_import": "dev-wombat",
    "cobweb/externalimport_test": "dev-master",
    "cobweb/svconnector": "dev-master",
    "cobweb/svconnector_csv": "dev-master",
    "cobweb/svconnector_feed": "dev-master",
    "cobweb/svconnector_json": "dev-master",
    "cobweb/svconnector_sql": "dev-master"
  },
  "extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
      "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
      "web-dir": "web"
    }
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "nimut/testing-framework": "^1.1"
  }
}
```

I don't understand exactly which parts of TYPO3 are initialized in the bootstrap process while running unit tests from the command line, but it seems incomplete.

Case in point: when I try to run unit tests for extension "svconnector_csv" using (in the "web" folder):

```
/path/to/php ../vendor/bin/phpunit -c ../vendor/nimut/testing-framework/res/Configuration/UnitTests.xml typo3conf/ext/svconnector_csv/Tests/Unit/
```

all tests fail, reporting an exception that no service key "tx_svconnectorcsv_sv1" can be found. The service is installed fine when checking in the backend (using the Reports module).

Another error, but also a problem, when running the tests for extension "external_import", using a similar command. I get errors indicating that the TCA is not loaded.

Can the bootstrap processed be influenced in any way to ensure that global arrays like TCA and T3_SERVICES are loaded? Or should they be and I'm missing something in my setup?

As a reference, here's the link to the source code of both extensions:

- https://github.com/cobwebch/external_import/
- https://github.com/cobwebch/svconnector_csv

Comment: Could it be that the test-framework has an installation of it's own that does not have that service installed?

Answer (score 1):

I use this testing-framework, too. I use it in GitLab CI and run my extension with:

```
.Build/bin/phpunit -c Configuration/.Build/Tests/UnitTests.xml
```

My UnitTests.xml:

```
<phpunit
    backupGlobals="true"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="../../../.Build/vendor/nimut/testing-framework/src/TestingFramework/Bootstrap/UnitTestsBootstrap.php"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    forceCoversAnnotation="false"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnError="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    stopOnIncomplete="false"
    stopOnSkipped="false"
    verbose="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Base tests">
            <directory>../../../Tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Hope, it helps.